# If there's a typo in my program's settings file, what is the proper way to handle it?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that reads the settings from a `settings.ini` file. If it comes across a typo or similar issue, what should it do?

Given a `settings.ini`-file's syntax is like this:

```
DefaultFolder = C:\Settings
Programversion = 0.52
```

If the program comes across, say, a spelling error, like this:

```
DefauFolder = C:\Settings
```

What should it do?

Comment: You, presumably, know your application better than we do. So you are better placed to answer this question. Perhaps I would make storing the settings part of the application, and make sure that at least a typo couldn't appear in 'DefaultFolder', and that the path 'C:\Settings' was a valid path at the time it was saved.

Comment: Why are you using an INI file instead of the built in, easy to use My Settings?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is, inevitably, 'Fail gracefully'. However, in the case of a settings file the 'fail' part is what is in question.

Typically, when a piece of code requires a setting, it will fail if it doesn't find that setting, throwing an appropriate error or exception. In that case, it is the code that needs the setting that should fail gracefully.

Also typical is to see a settings file that allows settings beyond what is strictly required. All additional settings are ignored. Whatever ingests the settings simply skips by them (or puts them in a registry, or what have you). But it still assumes the user knows what they are doing.

Anything more complex requires knowing a lot about user intent.

Given your specific example, this means:

- The `DefauFolder` setting is consumed by the setting ingester and placed in a registry or hashmap, where no one looks at it.
- When code needs the `DefaultFolder` setting, it looks in the settings registry and doesn't find it. It fails with an error message that says something like, "`DefaultFolder` setting is required in the ini file to complete , but could not be found."